# MySQL - Where clause processing order

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, coldfusion-9

This is a basic question. I inherited some code containing a cfquery. It runs on CF9 with MySQL 5.6. The cfquery reads:

```
SELECT some_columns 
FROM   tablename 
WHERE  itemname = 'itemnamevar' 
AND    id > 0 
ORDER BY orderby
```

The table contains more than 20000 items. ID is the primary key autoincrement value.
It looks to me like the previous coder used to put `id > 0` into the query to prepend some other clause conditions to the query. If none of them are used (controlled by some if/else), the `id > 0` should cause all data from the table to be selected.

So the code is used as:

```
SELECT some_columns
FROM   tablename
WHERE 
<cfif id>
   id = '###'
<cfelse>
   <cfif LEN(itemname)>
      itemname = 'itemnamevar' AND 
   </cfif>
   <cfif LEN(itemgroup)>
      itemgroup = 'itemgroupvar' AND 
   </cfif>
   id > 0
</cfif>
```

My question is: if all the other clauses minimize the query set, before the `id > 0` is processed, can I assume the `id > 0` will have no effect on performance or should I rewrite the code to remove that condition? This will take some time because there are plenty of queries to optimize.

I need to say that the website running this code has some heavy load (more than 200k visitors a month growing relatively quick).

Thanks in advance. Please let me know if you need further information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an expression that evaluates to TRUE without checking at the data. For example:

```
1 = 1
```

Comment: Thank you. This means that no "where" will be processed if the only condition is "1 = 1" and no other conditions takes place?

Comment: that's it, WHERE 1=1 would be the same as no where at all

Comment: Anyway, I think id > 0 should not impact the performance either, you can run some tests

Comment: Thank you very much. I will test it. The more interesting to me is, if the appended id > 0 produces some overhead. We will see.